# Snowflake error - 253003: While putting file(s) there was an error: 'HTTPError('403 Client Error: Forbidden for url

Tags: python, python-3.x, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have the following snowflake code which will basically connect to snowflake cloud after which I try to read local csv file to df and then push df to Snowflake cloud db

```
import pandas as pd

# The Snowflake Connector library.
import snowflake.connector as snow
from snowflake.connector.pandas_tools import write_pandas
from snowflake.connector.pandas_tools import pd_writer
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from urllib.parse import quote_plus

class SnowFlakeHelper:

    def __init__(self,CONFIG):
        self.account = CONFIG['snowflake_accountname']
        self.account_fullurl = CONFIG["snowflake_account_fullurl"]
        self.dbname = CONFIG['snowflake_dbname']
        self.tablename = CONFIG['snowflake_tablename']
        self.uname = CONFIG['snowflake_uname']
        self.password = CONFIG['snowflake_password']
        self.syncdatacsvpath = CONFIG['data_csv_path']
        self.cur,self.conn = self.connect()
        self.engine = self.connect_using_sqlalchemy()
    
    
    def connect_using_sqlalchemy(self):
        conn_string = f"snowflake://{self.uname}:{quote_plus(self.password)}@{self.account}/{self.dbname}/PUBLIC"
        engine = create_engine(conn_string)
        return engine
    
    def load_csv_with_sqlalchemy(self):
        df = pd.read_csv(self.syncdatacsvpath)
        if_exists = 'replace'

        #Write the data to Snowflake, using pd_writer to speed up loading
        print('.... Trying to send csv data to snowflake .....')
        with self.engine.connect() as con:
            df.to_sql(name=self.tablename.lower(), con=con, if_exists=if_exists, method=pd_writer, index=False)
```

Once I call the  load_csv_with_sqlalchemy() with the correct username, password, account details I am facing the following problem -

```
Exception has occurred: OperationalError
253003: While putting file(s) there was an error: 'HTTPError('403 Client Error: Forbidden for url: https://sfc-in-ds1-99-customer-stage.s3.amazonaws.com/3f0c0000-s/stages/decf206a-e8c1-484e-9231-5d7feaa038f0/file0.txt')', this might be caused by your access to the blob storage provider, or by Snowflake.
  File "D:\AAIN1464\reconciliation\lib\snowflake_helper.py", line 55, in load_csv_with_sqlalchemy
    df.to_sql(name=self.tablename.lower(), con=con, if_exists=if_exists, method=pd_writer, index=False)
  File "D:\AAIN1464\reconciliation\run.py", line 104, in sync_data
    snowflakehelper.load_csv_with_sqlalchemy()
  File "D:\AAIN1464\reconciliation\run.py", line 203, in <module>
    sync_data()
snowflake.connector.errors.OperationalError: 253003: While putting file(s) there was an error: 'HTTPError('403 Client Error: Forbidden for url: https://sfc-in-ds1-99-customer-stage.s3.amazonaws.com/3f0c0000-s/stages/decf206a-e8c1-484e-9231-5d7feaa038f0/file0.txt')', this might be caused by your access to the blob storage provider, or by Snowflake.
```

I tried using the write_pandas() function and gave all access to my account role and still facing the issue , wonder what is causing the problem here ?

From my debugger I know that the source of error is happening in the line below which means connection is successful but failing to add df data to snow flake due to some unknown restrictions -

```
df.to_sql(name=self.tablename.lower(), con=con, if_exists=if_exists, method=pd_writer, index=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
self.account_fullurl = CONFIG["snowflakt_account_fullurl"]
```

It seems like there is a typo in the key name. It should be:

```
self.account_fullurl = CONFIG["snowflake_account_fullurl"]
```

Comment: all CONFIG values contains the credentials and are coming from an env file so please ignore the typos in them as the source of error is happening in the line  - df.to_sql(name=self.tablename.lower(), con=con, if_exists=if_exists, method=pd_writer, index=False) which infers the connection is successful but for some unknown reasons table creation and data add is not happening